# MYSQL Prestashop 1.7 update price multistore

Tags: mysql, sql-update, prestashop-1.7, multistore

How do I run it for all rows of a given product id and shop id:

One table: ps_product_shop

| id_product | price | id_shop |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 25 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 50 | 3 |

THX

**For one line:** UPDATE ps_product_shop SET price=(SELECT price FROM ps_product_shop WHERE id_product = '1' AND id_shop = '1')*25 WHERE (id_product='1') AND (id_shop='3');

**I tried but it doesn't work:** UPDATE ps_product_shop SET price=(SELECT price FROM ps_product_shop WHERE id_product = ps_product_shop.id_product AND id_shop = '1')*25 WHERE ps_product_shop.id_product IN (SELECT price FROM ps_product_shop WHERE id_product = ps_product_shop.id_product AND id_shop = '3');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already figured it out, maybe it will help someone:

```
UPDATE ps_product_shop AS sk SET 
price=(SELECT price FROM ps_product_shop
WHERE id_product = sk.id_product AND id_shop = '1')*27 WHERE (sk.id_shop='3');
```

for all lines sk.id_shop='3'

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
UPDATE ps_product p, ps_product_shop ps 
SET p.price = p.price*25, ps.price = ps.price*25
WHERE p.id_product = 1 AND ps.id_product = 1 AND ps.id_shop = 2
```

Comment: Thank you but I meant for all lines at once.